# Excel fuzzy lookup just showing 000.01 or 000.00 values

Tags: excel, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to use this add-on but the results of similarity just show the 00.001 or 00.000 values regardless of the similarity threshold settings. Why am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at some of the YOUTUBE videos on using the add-in correctly?

Comment: Yes but i didn´t find any video that could explain this issue.

Comment: Please provide us more detail, a sample of the range you are querying , the settings you are using (a formula for example), the expected outcome vs. the actual outcome, etc.  We need to understand what you are doing , and how you are doing it , to better serve your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the format of the cell. Change it to percentages and then the number would change from your format 00.0001 to a real similarity percentage. Remember that the Fuzzy look up search value and gives you similarity rating that is measure in percentages.
Cheers!